# three.js Draw bounding box from 3d-force-graph

Tags: d3.js, three.js, bounding-box

I'm currently trying to calculate/draw the bounding box from a force graph using 3d-force-3d and three.js. I'm not having any luck creating the box. force-graph has a getGraphBbox() function but not much documentation. I have tried Any help would be appreciated! ...here is some not working code, i'm working with. Edit - my data is dynamic, I can add a mostly transparent cube to the scene around the points but in a static graph… I want the cube to always render the appropriate size around the nodes as some graphs have 1000 nodes and others 50 in my data sets. Hence the bounding box.

```
const Graph = ForceGraph3D()
      (document.getElementById('3d-graph'))
        .graphData(data)
        .nodeLabel('id')
        .nodeAutoColorBy('group');
        //.getGraphBbox();//Not sure how to use this 

    let helper = new THREE.Box3Helper(Graph, 0xff0000);
    helper.update();

    Graph.scene().add(helper)
```